# Move product toolbar in another phtml file

Tags: magento-2.0, product-list, category-listing

In **Product listing** page I've created a block and it's content coming from phtml file. So I wish to move product toolbar in it, so I've write following code in **catalog_category_view.xml** of my custom theme but it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns container">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.toggle" template="Magento_Catalog::category/toogle.phtml" before="main" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="category.toggle" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Any guesses what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: any ideas guys??